# When creating a Conan package, how can I export a package consumer conan recipe?

Tags: python, c++, package-managers, conan

I would like to know how to export a Conan recipe to be used by the consumer (which, among other things, will build the package from source and install the binaries in specific directories in the system) instead of the one I used to create the package.

I've been reading this section on Conan official documentation:

https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/mastering/conanfile_py.html#

but I don't seem to understand exactly how it works.

Comment: The recipe alone may not be enough, it could require conandata.yml as well. The safest way is by running `conan install <reference> --build=<package_name>`, on Conan 2.x is `conan install --requires=<rereference> -r <remote> --build=<package_name>`. Conan will download the recipe and build your package from source. The recipe will be located on export folder in your cache. Another unsafe option is `conan get`command, but it does not work on Conan 2.x

Comment: @uilianries  Will those commands download the recipe from a remote repository (e.g. Artifactory)? How would I upload the consumer recipe in the first place? As far as I can see, running 'conan create' along with the required arguments exports my recipe (not the consumer one) to the Conan cache.

Comment: Yes, conan create will download from an Artifactory instance. To upload you need to run the command `conan upload`: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/creator/upload.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't formulate my last question properly. What I meant is:  how could I export the consumer recipe to the Conan cache? In addition to/instead of my package creator recipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `'conan create'` command, I used `'conan export'` command with the following arguments:

```
conan export <consumer_conan_recipe> <package_name> -ks
```

where `-ks` prevents the command from removing the source folder in the local cache, even if the recipe changed (source: `'conan export --help'` command)